# Adding CoreUI to an existing react solution

Tags: reactjs, core-ui

I'm really new to react and want to build a small admin site using `CoreUI`. I've followed the instructions laid out https://www.npmjs.com/package/@coreui/react which are:

> npm install @coreui/coreui --save
>
> Add link to CSS in the header
>
> Add links to js at the bottom of the body

This is where react gets a little sketch for me but I think ive done it right. Ive imported a button component to try out.

```
import Button from '@coreui/coreui';
.
.
<Button block color="primary">Primary</Button>
```

Everything compiles but when I view the webpage I get a load of errors

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.
>
> createFiberFromTypeAndProps
>   C:/Code/temp/test-react-admin/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26573

At this point I'm at a complete loss as I've tried looking for this error and cant figure out what I must be doing wrong so any help would be very much appreciated.